# Extract currency symbol from price in Python

Tags: python

I am writing some code in Python where I am required to extract the currency symbol from a price. So,

```
cost = $56.78
```

I need to get just the '$'.

On these forums I found how to extract the number but not the currency symbol. I am new to regexes so would be grateful for help.

It could be any currency, not just dollar, but I suppose it would be the first character in the string..

Comment: If it's just the first character of a string: `cost[0]`. IIRC not all currencies do that though.

Comment: You also may want to look for a stream of non-numeric characters as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> def get_symbol(price):
        import re
        pattern =  r'(\D*)[\d\,\.]+(\D*)'
        g = re.match(pattern, price.strip()).groups()
        return (g[0] or g[1]).strip()

>>> get_symbol('$12.5')
'$'
>>> get_symbol('12.5USD')
'USD'
```

Comment: Very nice.  I like how you generalize it.

Comment: op is asking for currency symbol. I think `USD` is not a symbol.

Comment: you just need to strip any spaces from the result.  get_symbol(EUR 10,000.00) yields 'EUR '.

Comment: As alexander said, it won't deal with `EUR 10,000.00`

Answer (score 5):

The actual pattern to match all the currency symbols is `\p{Sc}`. But this regex won't be supported by python's default `re` module. But the the external [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module would support many PCRE regexes.

```
>>> cost = '$56.78'
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'\p{Sc}', cost)
['$']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vS1fU6/1)

**OR**

Just replace the numbers or spaces with an empty string through `re.sub` function.

```
>>> def get_symbol(price):
        return re.sub(r'\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?|\s+', '', price)

>>> get_symbol('EUR 10,000.00')
'EUR'
>>> get_symbol(' $ 12.5')
'$'
>>> get_symbol('12.5 USD')
'USD'
```

OR

Keep it simple.

```
>>> def get_symbol(price):
        return re.sub(r'[\d,.\s]', '', price)

>>> get_symbol('EUR 10,000.00')
'EUR'
>>> get_symbol(' $ 12.5')
'$'
>>> get_symbol('12.5 USD')
'USD'
```

Answer (score 0):

If `cost = '$56.78'` you just have to do `cost[0]` to get the "first character of the string":

```
>>> cost = $56.78     #<-- you can't do this cause its not a valid string
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> cost = '$56.78'   #valid string

>>> cost[0]
'$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cost is a string value, I would do the following:

```
cost = '$56.78';

currency = cost[:1]

print(currency)
```

Just grab the first value in the cost string and you will have your currency.

You could also do:

```
currency = cost[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach I can think of is to strip off any non currency symbol characters from the string

**Implementation**

```
def get_symbol(price):
    import string
    delete_chars = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.digits + u" ,.+-")
    price = unicode(price).translate(delete_chars)
    try:
        return price.decode('ascii').encode('ascii')
    except (UnicodeDecodeError,UnicodeEncodeError):
        return price
```

**Demo**

```
>>> print get_symbol(u' \u20B9 12.5')
₹
>>> get_symbol(u' \u20B9 12.5')
u'\u20b9'
>>> get_symbol('$12.5')
'$'
>>> get_symbol('12.5USD')
'USD'
>>> get_symbol('EUR 10,000.00')
'EUR'
>>> get_symbol(' $ 12.5')
'$'
```